# Create multiple header in php

Tags: php, url, pdf, redirect, header

I need to go to two different url in same time for create two pdf file .
Currently with my code, only the last redirection work , I want to redirect user to two url , how can I do this ?

```
 // I need to create 2 different pdf , (pdf is created when we go to create_Pdf.php)
  for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
    {
    header('Location: ../../Create_PDF.php?idcode='.$code.'&inputdate='.$datein.'&outputdate='.$dateoutfr.'&username='.$usernameOut);
    header('Location: ../../Create_PDF.php?idcode='.$code'&inputdate='.$datenominate.'&outputdate=31/12/2015&username='.$usernameIn);

    }
```

**** The pdf will be not output, only 2 pdf file will be create in a repository ***

Comment: Well, you'd better open two tab to do this.

Comment: @ôkio I don't want to two tab, It need to create two pdf

Comment: 1 tab = 1 url. You can create 2 PDF, but only one will be shown

Comment: @ôkio You can give me an example with a code, I don't understand what you say with tab

Comment: Redirect to the the second file in the first file, after the code execution is finished ..

Comment: @SyedQarib How, actually one pdf is created when I go to create_pdf.php , I need to create two pdf, how can I do ? foreach loop not work

Comment: "ping" both URLs with cURL? Unless you want to actually output the PDFs of course (depends on what your CreatePDF script actually does).

Comment: @CD001 have you got an example in PHP Code ?

Comment: Unless the PDFs are being saved to the server it won't work thinking about it, since you're outputting the PDF for the user to save I presume?

Comment: @CD001 The pdf will not be output , only 2 pdf will be create in a repository

Comment: It's convoluted but it should work then... http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @CD001 I need a code please

Answer (score 1):

You could use cURL for this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Essentially cURL allows you to contact URLs "behind the scenes" (rather than using an HTTP Redirect) - but there are several settings that will depend on your setup... and there are a lot of cURL settings: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php

However, in essence here you'll want a function which just contacts the given URL - maybe throws an Exception if the URL can't be reached.

```
function curlCreatePDF($sURL) {

    //open the cURL session
    $hCurl = curl_init();

    //set the cURL options
    curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL); //URL
    curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); //HTTP version
    curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); //no HTTP headers
    curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //return raw data to script rather than browser
    curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); //set timeout

    //execute
    curl_exec($hCurl); //this will actually return the response

    //throw an Exception if cURL failed
    if($e = curl_error($hCurl)) {
        throw new Execption($e, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    //close the cURL handle
    curl_close($hCurl);
}

// I need to create 2 different pdf , (pdf is created when we go to create_Pdf.php)
try {
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
        curlCreatePDF("http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/Create_PDF.php?idcode={$code}&inputdate={$datein}&outputdate={$dateoutfr}&username={$usernameOut}");
        curlCreatePDF("http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/Create_PDF.php?idcode={$code}&inputdate={$datenominate}&outputdate=31/12/2015&username={$usernameIn}");
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

This may not work "as is", especially over SSL (as you'll need to set the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` options)...

---

It would make more sense though to just put your **create PDF** stuff into a class and then just call it in your loop rather than calling an external file over HTTP.